# Setting up content scripts for different sites in google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I looked at the google-chrome-extension labs page and I don't see any example where you can use different content scripts for different sites. They have a page showing how to have multiple content scripts on one site, but not the reverse. Is there any way to have different content scripts for different sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["script1.js"]
    },{
      "matches": ["http://www.yahoo.com/*"],
      "js": ["script2.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```