# how to resume script when new window loads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing an page action extension for Google Chrome.  The extension injects the following script into a search page after it loads.  After the script finds all the occurrences of class "f_foto" (typically 10 items), it finds the first link in each of them, puts these hrefs in an array and then iterates thru the array opening a new window for each link and examining the result.  That's what it is supposed to do.

Everything works ok in this code except the last part. The new window opens in a new tab (I have tabs permission) but it only finishes loading after the script finishes.  Each new window overwrites the previous one in the same tab which would be ok if I had a chance to examine the contents first.  So if I run it without using the debugger when the script finishes the new tab contains the last item in the array and focus is on the new tab.  As far as I can see, handleResponse is never called.

If I run it in the DOM inspector and stop it at window.open, I can see that the new tab opens with "About Blank" in the title and the tab shows a spinning thingy showing that it is loading.  Stepping thru the code, detailWin remains undefined even after `detailWin=window.open(profileLinks[i], "Detail Window");` is executed.  I've tried replacing `window.onload = handleResponse;` with `detailWin.onload =handleResponse;` but in this case detailWin is undefined.

It seems to me I need to add an event listener that fires when the new window is loaded and executes handleResponse.  Yes?  No?

```
//PEEK.JS//
var req;
var detailWin;
var profileLinks = new Array();
function handleResponse() 
{
//  var contentDetail = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
    alert("Examine Detail Page Here");
};

//drag off the f_foto class
var searchResult = document.getElementsByClassName("f_foto");
alert("Found Class f_foto "+searchResult.length+" times.");

//collect profile links
for (var i = 0; i<searchResult.length; ++i) 
{
    var profileLink=searchResult[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    profileLinks[i]=profileLink[0].href;
//  alert(i+1+" of "+searchResult.length+" "+profileLinks[i]+" length of "+profileLinks[i].length);
}
for (var i = 0; i<searchResult.length; ++i) 
{

//DYSFUNCTIONAL CODE: New window finishes loading only after script completes, how to execute handleResponse?

    detailWin=window.open(profileLinks[i], "Detail Window");
    window.onload = handleResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1:** make [two separated content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287633/setting-up-content-scripts-for-different-sites-in-google-chrome/6287732#6287732) - one for the search page only, one for the profile page only. Search script would only open profile link, profile script would only process it (contains code inside your `handleResponse()`)

**Option #2** If for some reasons you don't want to inject profile script to all profile pages, only to those you opened yourself from the search page, then instead of opening windows from a content script you should send a message to a background page asking it to open a profile link in a new tab and inject your profile script.

You still will have two content scripts.

**search.js** (injected to search pages only):

```
//PEEK.JS//
var req;
var detailWin;

//drag off the f_foto class
var searchResult = document.getElementsByClassName("f_foto");
alert("Found Class f_foto "+searchResult.length+" times.");

//collect profile links
for (var i = 0; i<searchResult.length; ++i) 
{
    var profileLink=searchResult[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    profileLinks[i]=profileLink[0].href;
//  alert(i+1+" of "+searchResult.length+" "+profileLinks[i]+" length of "+profileLinks[i].length);
}
for (var i = 0; i<searchResult.length; ++i) 
{
    //tell bkgd page to open link
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "openProfile", url: profileLinks[i]});
}
```

**profile.js** (will be injected to profile pages you opened)

```
var contentDetail = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
alert("Examine Detail Page Here");
```

**background.html:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "openProfile") {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: request.url}, function(tab){
            //profile tab is created, inject profile script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "profile.js"});
        });
    }
});
```

**Option #3:** Maybe you don't need to create profile window at all? If all you need is to find something in the page source, then you can just [load that page through ajax](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/xhr.html) and parse it (you would need to do it in a background page).

Comment: Wouldn't another option be to load it in an IFRAME?

Comment: very elegant, thank you.  can i pass the array to the background page as a reference to profileLinks or will i need to build a json structure by iterating thru profileLinks[i]?

Comment: As you may have noticed from my recent post, I have decided to send over the target links one at a time and I'm having trouble with the messaging again.  But if I just passed over the whole array the first time, I could process it in background without requesting anything more from the content script.  The array is named profileLinks and contains 25 items.  Would I pass it over to background this way: chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "openProfile", urlList: profileLinks});   ????????????  As I understand an array in javascript is not the same as an array in json.